# Group By is not aggregating

Tags: c#, linq

I am aggregating data that I retrieve from multiple identical web services. The same row count and data points are returned with only a variance in the `Value`. The GroupBy clause I am using is not condensing any of the rows.  I have the same row count before and after the GroupBy.

```
MyWebServiceUrls
    .AsParallel()
    .SelectMany(url => GetMetricItemData(url))
    .GroupBy(item => new { item.DateTime, item.Group, item.Metric }, item => item.Value)
    .Select(grp => new MetricItem()
    {
        DateTime = grp.Key.DateTime,
        Group = grp.Key.Group,
        Metric = grp.Key.Metric,
        Value = // type = decimal?
            grp.Any(mi => mi.HasValue)
            ? grp.Key.Metric.AggregationType == Metric.MetricAggregationTypes.Sum
                ? grp.Sum(mi => mi.Value)
                : grp.Average(mi => mi)
            : null
    })
    .AsEnumerable();
```

The syntax looks correct based on other examples I have found.

I send this data back to my database and can aggregate with the statement `GROUP BY [DateTime], [Group], [Metric]` and everything works great.  While I can use the database to solve this issue, I would like to know how to correctly use LINQ in this instance.

What am I missing to get this LINQ expression to work?

UPDATE:

This is the relevant MetricItem and Metric class definition:

```
public class MetricItem
{
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public Metric Metric { get; set; }
    public Decimal? Value { get; set; }
}

public class Metric
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }

    private List<string> SumMetrics = new List<string>(new string[] { "TPI", "TPO", "TPIO" });
    public enum MetricAggregationTypes { Sum, Average };
    public MetricAggregationTypes AggregationType
    {
        get
        {
            if (SumMetrics.IndexOf(this.Code) >= 0)
                return MetricAggregationTypes.Sum;
            else
                return MetricAggregationTypes.Average;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you getting back now (with your current implementation)?

Comment: Your expression looks fine. Are you *really* sure that `DateTime`, `Group` and `Metric` are actually equal?

Comment: Need the class definition for MetricItem

Comment: I solved the issue when I grouped by the Metric fields instead of simply `Metric`.  To all those wayward linq neophytes like myself, this is a simple case of incorrect equality checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on the `Metric` class. Most Linq methods use hash codes for comparison operations, so for most objects you define yourself, you need to override this class if you plan to use something like `GroupBy`, `Union`, etc.

Comment: This worked for me!  In this case I only needed to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for the `Metric` class as I am only grouping on a subset of fields in the `MetricItem` object.

Comment: @CElliott Good! I should mention that if you don't have those overridden, it compares on reference equality instead (Meaning are these literally the same object, not just the same value), which since you are generating them on the fly in the group by, will be false.